# Problem to porting managed c++ from vs2003 to vs2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, managed, visual-studio-2003

In trying to port my managed c++ project from vs2003 to vs2008. I have added oldSyntax flag. But I still get error sourceanotations.h.

Comment: Please put the exact error and the code in the question -- there is no way to help without this.

Answer (score 1):

We have a project that was written with the managed extensions for C++ that simply doesn't compile in VS2005 using /clr:oldSyntax.

Unfortunately your choices are either to keep building it with VS2003 or translate it to C++/CLI (or complaining the Microsoft, but I wouldn't hold out too much hope there).

We've done the translation on a number of projects and it is tedious, but fairly straight forward.

Or if there is another solution out there I'd like to here it so we can retire the build machine we still have running VS2003 just for this purpose!